# How to call another Content from the same page with onclick Like sign up or Log in

Tags: javascript, html, css

For Example i onclick on Sign up or Log in  button then on that page all other contends will be hidden in div only, then input register or Log in page comes in. Again every time i want go back to log in i click the link then register or login page will be hiddeden then [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f11qY.jpg)Could Any body Tell me How To do that

AFTER ONCLICK EITHER OF THEM

THIS SHOULD APPEAR WITH THE LINK I EITHER GO BACK LOGIN OR JUST COMPLETE THE INPUT

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS on here, it means you are shouting.

Comment: Add your code please. Post a simple example so that others can help you - you should [edit] your question to do that. We can't help with what we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use specific URL's and let the links navigate between sign up and the logged in page/initial site. Or use a framework e.g. KnockoutJS  to dynamically load/unload content.